# laravel-5.7:: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

Hi I'm trying to open a page but it says:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

**Picture** of folders:

[image]

**route**:

```
  Route::match(['get','post'], 'CategoriesController@index');
```

**controller**:

```
  public function index()
  {
    return view('admin.categories.index');
  }
```

any suggestion to resolve this `issue`?

Comment: please share your routes...php artisan route:list. the answer is probably there..

Comment: route list  https://ibb.co/Vxc7KyC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the url it self.

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', 'Controller@action');
```

Comment: You can also use an action instead of a closure: `Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'admin/categories', 'CategoriesController@index')`. Closure based routes cannot be cached.

Comment: sory same error can u plz see it https://ibb.co/Vxc7KyC   and using this url ../public/admin/categories/index is it correct?

Comment: See the comment of @piscator above. Just add the url parameter 'admin/categories'

Comment: you didnt change anything.. http://prntscr.com/mmq0aw  can you spot the differences? Base on your routes your url is CategoriesController@index and you have no action which is wrong. See the blue is what you do and white is what is should be like

Comment: that means that  you dont have a controller named CategoriesController. check if you have misspelled your controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188611/discussion-between-programmer0001-and-daenerystarg).

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is the url and you are missing it that is way in your `route:list` shows `CategoriesController@index` as the url.

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/categories',CategoriesController@index);
```

Check that you are putting the right url on your link bottom.